# xslt count sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, count

I have a sample":

```
<Root>
    <A rename="yes,it is option 1"/>
    <C rename="no"/>
    <A rename="yes,it is option 2"/>
    <C rename="no"/>
    <C rename="yes"/>
    <C rename="no"/>  
    <A rename="yes,it is option 3"/>
    <A rename="yes,it is option 4"/>
    <C rename="no"/>
    <C rename="yes"/>
    <C rename="no"/>      
    <C rename="no"/>        
</Root>
```

Then I apply a template look like this:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="A">
            <p><b>option1: <xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::C[preceding-sibling::A[1]/@rename[contains(.,'option 1')]])"/></b></p>
            <p><b>option2: <xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::C[preceding-sibling::A[1]/@rename[contains(.,'option 2')]])"/></b></p>            
            <p><b>option3: <xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::C[preceding-sibling::A[1]/@rename[contains(.,'option 3')]])"/></b></p>
            <p><b>option4: <xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::C[preceding-sibling::A[1]/@rename[contains(.,'option 4')]])"/></b></p>                        
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but i want the output look like this,if there are not sibling following A, we just ignore this one.just print these @rename contains "option" and also contains  elements

```
option1: 1 

option2: 3 

option4: 4
```

What I get now is:

```
option1: 1 

option2: 3 

option3: 0 

option4: 4 

option1: 0 

option2: 3 

option3: 0 

option4: 4 

option1: 0 

option2: 0 

option3: 0 

option4: 4 

option1: 0 

option2: 0 

option3: 0 

option4: 4
```

Comment: Now that's a pretty good example how not to use XML. Why use a structured format when you don't give your data any structure?

Comment: Also *you did not actually try* your shown XSLT code with your input. I get pretty much the output you want. Please put some more diligence in your question, it's impossible to help you if your code and your question text tell two different stories.

Comment: i just want to simplify my original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting all the **C** elements that follow the most recent **A** element. This is can be done by means of a key, to group all such **C** elements with the associated **A** element

```
<xsl:key name="lookup" match="C" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::A[1])" />
```

To find **A** elements for which at least one following **C** exists, you then do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="A[key('lookup', generate-id())]" />
```

And then to count the number of options, you can just count the number of elements in the key, like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('lookup', generate-id()))" />
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="lookup" match="C" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::A[1])" />

    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="A[key('lookup', generate-id())]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@rename, ': ', count(key('lookup', generate-id())) , '&#13;&#13;')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to you XML sample, the following is output:

```
yes,it is option 1: 1

yes,it is option 2: 3

yes,it is option 4: 4
```

Note that if you wanted to 'option1' instead of 'yes, it is option 1', you could do `concat('option', substring-after(@rename, 'option '))` instead of just `@rename`

Note, this issue could be simplified, if you re-structured your XML. Something like this would be much better:

```
<Root>
    <A rename="yes,it is option 1">
        <C rename="no"/>
    </A>
    <A rename="yes,it is option 2">
        <C rename="no"/>
        <C rename="yes"/>
        <C rename="no"/>
    </A>
    <A rename="yes,it is option 3"/>
    <A rename="yes,it is option 4">
        <C rename="no"/>
        <C rename="yes"/>
        <C rename="no"/>
        <C rename="no"/>
    </A>
</Root>
```

Comment: but  A and C elements are not parent and child they are just siblings,

Comment: Yes, I know! I was just saying it would be easy to code your XSLT if they were parent and child.

Comment: yeah，i am more confused about dealing with these sibling relationship

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 this turns into an easy grouping issue, using the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction.

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="A" select="*">
    <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) != 1">
      <p>Option <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(current-group()[1]/@rename, 'option ')"/> = <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())-1"/></p>        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: it seems interesting, where can i find more examples like this?

Comment: I learnt everything I know about XSLT 2.0 from a book, the excellent XSLT 2.0 Programmers Reference from Wrox.

Comment: oh thank you very much ,is this one XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference, 3rd Edition
Michael Kay
ISBN: 978-0-7645-6909-8
Paperback
960 pages
August 2004
View Most Recent Edition of This Title

Comment: 4th edition is the latest, but yes, that's the right book. (ISBN 978-0470192740)

Comment: Amazon reports that that book is available for the Kindle, and you can check on www.wrox.com to see if it available in other formats.

Comment: i found a  pdf one  from a website. thank you if you want i can send to your mail